# Observing frequent log file switches depsite increasing the redo log size

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We had redo log sized 256m and then bumped it up to 512 and eventually 1024M and currently have 8 logs. Despite that we are observing log switch happenign every 1minute and it is eating into our performance,

A snapshot from  AWR

```
Load Profile

Per Second  Per Transaction Per Exec    Per Call
DB Time(s): 1.0 0.1 0.00    0.01
DB CPU(s):  0.6 0.1 0.00    0.01
Redo size:  34,893.0    4,609.0      

 Instance Activity Stats - Thread Activity
 Statistics identified by '(derived)' come from sources other than SYSSTAT
 Statistic  Total   per Hour
 log switches (derived) 82  59.88
```

Any suggestions on how to reduce the number of log file switches, I have read that ideally it should be about 1 switch in 15-20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

34893 bytes of redo per second = 125614800 bytes per hour, that is about 120 MB, nowhere near the size of 1 redo log group.

Based on this and the size of the redo logs, I would say something forces log switches periodically. The built-in parameter `archive_lag_target` forces a log switches after the specified amount of seconds elapses, that is the first thing I would check. Other than that, it could be anything else logging in to the database and forcing a log switch manually, e.g a cron job. (60 log switches per 60 minutes, thats quite suspicious)

Comment: I agree, seems like first thing to look for is there is a scheduled job somewhere running a script with a rogue ""ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE" or "ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG CURRENT" being issued.

Comment: SQL> show parameter archive_lag_target

    NAME                                 TYPE                             VALUE
    ------------------------------------ -------------------------------- -----------------      -------------
    archive_lag_target                   integer                          0

Comment: Thank you, its actually correct there was a crontab entry to switch a log file every minute.

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/oraclesw/product/11.2.0/db
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=****
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
alter system switch logfile;
exit
EOF


Have commented it now..

Comment: Thank you, its actually correct there was a crontab entry to switch a log file every minute.